# Can I have multiple colors in a single TextBlock in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I have a line  of text in a textblock that reads:

"Detected [gesture] with an accuracy of [accuracy]"

In WPF, is it possible for me to be able to change the color of the elements within a textblock?  Can I have a textblock be multiple colors?  For example, I would like the whole TextBlock to be black except the gesture name, which I would like to be red.

Is this possible in WPF?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
 <TextBlock>
      Detected
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gesture}" Foreground="Red" />
      with an accuracy of
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Accuracy}" />
 </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Only issue is that these 4 areas of text (`Detected`, `Gesture`, `with an accuracy of`, and `Accuracy`) will not be on the same line - they'll be single-spaced on different lines, instead. But I like the concept.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is like this( not styling for textblock):

```
<TextBlock  FontSize="25" >
   <Run Text="Detected [" Foreground="Red"/><Run Text="gesture" Foreground="Gray"/>
   <Run Text="] with an accuracy of [" Foreground="Yellow"/><Run Text="accuracy]" Foreground="Green"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Note: every enter(or new line) between Run tag make have space between them.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but have you tried this??
You can actually add multi colored text, this way in a TextBlock..

```
Xaml: <TextBlock x:Name="txt_Txt"/>


foreach (var itm5 in "! Hello World !; %Hello World%".Split(';'))
{
       if (txt_Txt.Inlines.Count() > 0)
           txt_Txt.Inlines.Add(new Run("\r\n"));
       foreach (var letter in itm5)
       {
            if (char.IsSymbol(letter))
               txt_Txt.Inlines.Add(new Run(letter.ToString()) { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
            else
                txt_Txt.Inlines.Add(new Run(letter.ToString()) { Foreground = Brushes.Black });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612650(v=VS.100).aspx) for that and set `IsReadOnly = true`