# WPF TextBlock Color for each Character

Tags: wpf, colors, textblock

how to get each character of a textblock of different color in wpf?

Answer (score 64):

Use many different ***runs***:

```
 <TextBlock FontSize="22">
            <Run Foreground="Gold">H</Run>
            <Run Foreground="Maroon">e</Run>
            <Run Foreground="Blue">l</Run>
            <Run Foreground="Orange">l</Run>
            <Run Foreground="Brown">o</Run>
        </TextBlock>
```

This produce the result:
[image]

Comment: How can I do this with MVVM?

Comment: Bind `TextBlock` text to a list of `Runs`?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman You can't bind `List<Run>` to `Text` property of `TextBlock`. But you can bind to `Text` value of individual `Run`. Try: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705444/can-i-have-multiple-colors-in-a-single-textblock-in-wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705444/can-i-have-multiple-colors-in-a-single-textblock-in-wpf)

Comment: @EmpereurAiman After small research, found way to bind. Please refer this. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines#9546372](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines#9546372)