# How to forecolor a specific keyword in a string?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model-binding, textblock

I have a list :

Name
Age
Description

which I need to display in a grid.

How to display the binded property of Description to grid 
where if a description contain a specific keyword as "Good","Kind" then it must be highlighted in such a way that for "Good" it must be pink
and for "Kind" it must be in Red .

Example

Name    Age   Description

ABC  25     I am very Good person

XYZ     28    I am very Kind person

PQR     26    I am a jovial kind of person.

I need to use this MVVM

Model:

```
 private string name    
 public string Name { get { return name } set { name    = value; } }

 private int age
 public int Age{ get { return age}    set { age= value; }   }

 private string description
 public string Description{ get { return description} set { description= value; } }
```

In Xaml :-

```
<TextBlock  Name="tbDescription"   Text="{Binding RowData.Row.Description, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MinWidth="300">
```

Comment: I want only the "Good" keyword forecolor in Pink and the rest part of Description in Black

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535619/wpf-textblock-color-for-each-character and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `ValueConverter` to return the color you need based on the string.

```
public class ForeGroundColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = (string)value;

        if(color.IndexOf("good", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            // return 'Good' color.
        }
        else if (color.IndexOf("kind", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            // return 'Kind' color.
        }
        // More cases.
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use this converter in your binding. (Apply to the control you need. I use TextBlock as an example.)

```
<TextBlock Name="Your text." 
           ForeGround={Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource ForeGroundColorConverter}/>
```

First add it to your XML namespaces:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:<YourNameSpace>"
```

You will need to add a resource to your window/control as well.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters.ForeGroundColorConverter x:Key="ForeGroundColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: will the specifc keyword for example "good"  color only change ...?? using this logic..I dont want the whole sentence to change its color @burnttoast11

Comment: I want to check if it contains that specifc keyword ,highlight only that word

Comment: Updated answer to use `.IndexOf` to do a case insensitive search.

Comment: I have binded in xaml : <TextBlock  Name="tbDescription"   Text="{Binding RowData.Row.Description, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MinWidth="300">

Comment: You will need to add the `ForeGround` attribute to your TextBlock with the binding provided in the answer.

Comment: what about updation part,if the string gets updated in application will the binding be same?

Comment: No, you will keep that. You will have multiple bindings on your TextBlock. But I just noticed that you want to only change the color of the keyword. That makes it a bit more complicated. I think this is becoming more complex than can be answered in a single question.

Comment: yes ,its complex I have checked For Textblock.Inlines  and using Span but that  didn't work for me.,I just need to highlight only the keyword in that sentence

Comment: I can't access the chats

Comment: I 'm getting the whole string highlighted