# How to change color of part of text in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have such ListView

```
...
            <ListView
                x:Name="LVLog"
                ToolTip="Log of task(s) execution"
                Background="WhiteSmoke"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
...
```

There is how I set items

```
LVLog.Items.Add(message.Log);
```

And there `ToString()` method of object that I try to bind

```
public override string ToString() => string.Format("You are <span style='color:red'>{0}</span> km. in city <span style='color:red'>{1}</span> km.", 100, 136);
```

So, I expect to get 100  and 136 in red color, but actually I get this

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why it does not format text as expected?

Comment: `ListView` doesn't support this.

Comment: @MatthewWatson so, there is no way to get colored text in ListView, right?

Comment: You are not allowed to do that, xaml doesn't support css tags. You can split a `TextBlock` into `Run` elements and set the background color for every item separately

Comment: Alas, no - not without going owner-draw (which is a lot of work). You can only change the foreground and background text colour.

Comment: You may look up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246795/change-selection-color-of-wpf-listviewitem), it may help you to color the whole line.

Comment: A RichTextBox instead of a TextBlock may solve the problem

Comment: See also [WPF TextBlock Color for each Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535619/wpf-textblock-color-for-each-character)

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <TextBlock Text="You are "/>
    <TextBlock Text="100" Foreground="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Text=" km. in city "/>
    <TextBlock Text="136" Foreground="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Text=" km."/>
</TextBlock>
```

html is not interpreted in TextBlock