# Can you, and if so how, do you style sections of a WPF TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have multiple colors in a single TextBlock in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705444/can-i-have-multiple-colors-in-a-single-textblock-in-wpf)

Is it possible to style sections of a WPF TextBlock, such as a certain word to be bold, italic or underlined? Can you change all font properties? If so, what solution is the prettiest and most performance effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can style runs individually within a TextBlock in XAML, or you can use the [`Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) property in your .cs codebehind file. [This blog post](http://asimsajjad.blogspot.com/2010/08/wpf-textblock-inline-property.html) indicates that you can style at least font style, font weight, foreground color, and font size.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock>
     <Run Text="SomeText" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>
     <Run Text=" some more text" FontSize="12"/>
     <Run Text=" and more" Foreground="Blue"/>
</TextBlock >
```

And here's an example showing adding a brush to the run from [C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/textblock-in-wpf/):

```
<Run.Foreground>
   <LinearGradientBrush>
      <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.0" />
      <GradientStop Color="Purple" Offset="0.25" />
      <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.5" />
      <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
   </LinearGradientBrush>
</Run.Foreground>
```

The `Inlines` collection you can access programmatically is a collection of [`System.Windows.Documents.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx) objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **Runs**, you can put as many of them in a **TextBlock** or **Paragraph** as you'd like, and they're very efficient performance wise.

You can also use a binding for the *Text* property of a Run, pretty cool!

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="I want to show you some" />
    <Run Text="bold"
         FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Run Text="text!" />
</TextBlock>
```